# 8 coins lying on the table; you can flip one at a time; what is the minimum number of flips to get all heads or all tails?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle

The rules of the game are as follows:

(1) You can flip (turn it over) one coin at a time.

(2) You can't see the coins, but you can query after each flip, if you've reached the all heads or all tails state.

(3)

Apparently the answer is $2^{n-1} - 1 = 2^{7} - 1 = 127$ (this formula generalizes to any $n$, number of tosses).

I have no idea where this formula came from. Could someone explain?

I found a paper on it http://people.csail.mit.edu/nbenbern/CoinFlipping.pdf, but I haven't wrapped my head around it on how it works.

Comment: The rules aren't clear.  Do you see the coins?   Does "flip" mean "turn over" ?  If so,  $127$ seems awfully high.

Comment: This seems wrong. Say you have 7 heads and 1 tails. Reflip the tails coin and it comes up tails 128 times in a row. While improbably it's possible so this minimum seems insufficient.

Comment: @lulu Just updated the OP to address the rules, but the answer is no and yes, respectively.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Just edited the OP. The primary thing is you can't see the coins. You only know whether or not you've reached the goal state after a flip.

Comment: And are we told initially whether we have all the same at the start? (without wasting a "flip")?

Comment: Well... as a naive approach., just leave the first coin alone.  Before even doing the first flip you can presumably ask if you've won before having even started.  Supposing not, then cycle through all $2^{n-1}$ ways of having changed all other coins other than the first, eventually they will all match the first.

Comment: To state the obvious:  Leave coin $n$ as it is, and run through all $2^{n-1}$ possibiities for the rest.  You  get the first one for free, I am guessing.

Comment: As for why this is actually the minimum and no better strategy exists... that might take some thought.  I would expect, though, that this question is thoroughly explored in the linked paper already.

Comment: @lulu Yes, or you can assume that you don't start at the all heads or all tails state

Comment: @JMoravitz I thought of that approach as well. But I am not sure how to prove optimality. Also, there are $2^{n - 1}$ ways, and if you imagine each way as a node on a graph and the edges connecting a node to another node as a flip of any of the 8 coins, how do you show that all the nodes only need to be visited at most once once? I.e., how do you prove there exists a path such that you don't need to visit a node more than once?

Comment: That is explained in the linked article.  We need to visit every vertex or it's complement at least once each, hence the minimum of $2^{n-1}$ states we need to have checked (*one of which was the initial configuration, meaning $2^{n-1}-1$ flips*).  As for showing that we can make a path through that visits each vertex along our route at most once each, that can be done by using your favorite hamiltonian path around the $(n-1)$-cube corresponding to having left the first coin untouched.  That there exists a hamiltonian path through a cube is a well known elementary graph theory exercise.

Comment: @JMoravitz For the optimality, are you referring to pg 4, the 3rd paragraph where it states "In order for the magician to be sure of visiting one of the two solution states, the chosen path (sequence
of coin flips) must visit either v or its inversion $\bar{v}$ for every vertex v in the hypercube"? If so, I don't see how that's a proof? I don't get why we must visit all these vertices

Comment: Because suppose we did not visit either of $v$ or $\overline{v}$... then it is possible in the worst case that $v$ was the "all heads" configuration and $\overline{v}$ was the "all tails" configuration.  Having not reached $v$ or $\overline{v}$ then we will have not reached the end state, regardless how many other vertices we have visited.

Comment: @JMoravitz Right, I get that, but my concern the optimality is if there exists some path such that guarantees we can get to the goal without having to traverse all vertices. It seems there isn't

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123186/discussion-between-jmoravitz-and-user5965026).

Answer (score 1):

Given $n$ number of coins on the table, there are $2^n$ possible sequences of heads or tails. You can ignore the first coin, and then go through every possible permutation of the other $n-1$. As you are checking every single permutation, one of them is guaranteed to be all heads or all tails. This gives you a minimum of $2^{n-1}$ flips. *However*, because there is an original permutation of coins that is not all heads or all tails, there is one position you will not have to check, giving the final expression of $2^{n-1}-1$.